# mysql how to use two field as primary key and unique

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL database I have the data

```
create table student(user_id int(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(20),
email varchar(20),
primary key(user_id,email));
```

I want to use `user_id` and `email` field should be unique value.
I also add

```
alter table student add unique unique_index (user_id,email);
```

but still it accepts all the entry

```
mysql> insert into student (name, email) values ("a", "aa", "aa");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into student (name, email) values ("a", "aa", "aa");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)



 select * from student;
+---------+------+-------+
| user_id | name | email |
+---------+------+-------+
|       1 | a    | aa    |
|       2 | a    | aa    |
+---------+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

how can I make that fields(id and email) as unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like these. Here every unique index name should be different.

```
CREATE TABLE student(user_id INT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
NAME VARCHAR(20),
email VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY(user_id,email));
```

unique index creation.

```
ALTER TABLE student ADD UNIQUE unique_index1 (user_id);
ALTER TABLE student ADD UNIQUE unique_index2 (email);
```

Inserting data:

```
INSERT INTO student (`name`, email) VALUES ("a", "aa");
```

Execute below SQL it gives error.

```
INSERT INTO student (`name`, email) VALUES ("a", "aa");
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As my understandind of your requirement is correct, you have to add to unique indexes:

```
alter table student add unique unique_index (user_id);
alter table student add unique unique_index_email (email);
```

Your statement will create a index where the combination of user_id and email is unique!